# How to delete selected document ID from Firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

As in title. I have a String `shoppingListId` which holds current clicked in `RecyclerView` documentID and I wonder how to delete this selected document ID.

I tried the following one but it doesn't works because of Incompatible types:

```
FirebaseFirestore docRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
DocumentReference selectedDoc = docRef.collection("products").document(shoppingListId);
selectedDoc.delete();
```

How to get Instance to DocumentReference, and then delete selected document? I guess this is probably so easy, but Im stuck at it.

[image: View of database]

Changed the code, there aren't any Errors right now, but still it doesn't works.

Comment: If you're seeing an error, please copy that into your question.

Comment: What do you see in logcat that might be helpful?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are following this **[tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee)**, which is actually made by me.

The problem in your code is in the following line:

```
DocumentReference selectedDoc = docRef.collection("products").document(shoppingListId);
```

You cannot delete a product using only that line of code. Your code is not complete. To solve this, change that line with:

```
DocumentReference productIdRef = rootRef.collection("products").document(shoppingListId)
            .collection("shoppingListProducts").document(productId);
productIdRef.delete().addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> Snackbar.make(shoppingListViewFragment, "Product deleted!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show());
```

If you want to delete a ShoppingList, first you need to delete everything that is beneath it. So in order to delete a particular shopping list, first you need to find all the documents beneath the `shoppingListProducts` collection, delete them and right after that you'll be able to delete the `shoppingListId` document.

Comment: That's right Alex, I followed your tutorial, I have to say that it's great but I don't get this thing with references in Firebase :/ According to your response, maybe that was the issue because I tried to delete a document with some collections assigned to it. Am I supposed to delete all products that are added to this shoppingList first and then the empty document? I will try :)

Comment: I managed to delete from view and from database currently selected shoppingListId.
The following code solved half of my question:

FirebaseFirestore docRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
DocumentReference selectedDoc = docRef
.collection("shoppingLists")
.document(userEmail)
.collection("userShoppingLists")
.document(shoppingListId);
selectedDoc.delete();

But there are still products of this list remaining in databse and Im stuck here again, because I dont know how to delete all documents with productId from selected shoppingListId at once from selected collection.

Comment: You say that "are still products of this list remaining in databse ". The products within a shopping list exist only beneath a shopping list. At least this is what I did in that tutorial. If you have saved the product in another place, then in same way you added them, you need to delete them. There is a write batch that can help. See also my answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49125183/how-to-model-this-structure-to-handle-delete). Please, keep me posted.

Comment: Is there everything alright? Have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 2):

```
FirebaseFirestore docRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
docRef.collection("products").document(shoppingListId)
     .delete()
     .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
           
           // You can write what you want after the deleting process.
     })
     .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
     @Override
     public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                       
     }
     });
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/27780780)

Answer (score 0):

```
DocumentReference documentReference = firestore.collection("products").document(productid);
                                            documentReference.delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                        Toast.makeText(Payment_Successful.this, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    } else {
                                                        Toast.makeText(Payment_Successful.this, "Not", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    }
                                                }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).