# delete multiple documents in Firebase Firestore (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I build social media android app (like Instagram).

I am trying to delete multiple documents in a collection in Fire store,
but i didn't find information about how its done in android.

I made reference to the collection, and a Query with that reference (with a condition)
and I assume I need to use batch but I cant find how.

my Database structure is:

```
feed/
    user_id/
        posts/
            post_id(its Document - the post itself)
```

and the code for finding the relevent posts to delete is:

```
db.collection(DBConst.DB_FEED).document(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())
.collection(DBConst.DB_POSTS).whereEqualTo(DBConst.DB_UID, currUserId);
```

how should it done?

Comment: we cant help if you dont provide the code that you have tried, and point out where are you having troubles

Comment: Unless you show what you've tried already, it is going to be hard to help better than the documentation already does: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes

Comment: i edit the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to model this structure to handle delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49125183/how-to-model-this-structure-to-handle-delete)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no straight forward solution... however you can use batch  delete.

```
val batch = db.batch()
db.collection(...).whereEqualTo(...).get().result.forEach { 
    batch.delete(it.reference) 
}
batch.commit()
```