# Cannot delete multiple documents in Firebase Cloud Firestore

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing an Android Q&A application. I'd like users to delete all of their posts when they delete their accounts. I found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50456434/delete-multiple-documents-in-firebase-firestore-android) so I tried the same code, but it didn't work.
This is my code.

```
@Composable
fun DeleteAccounts(navController: NavController, uid: String) {
    val db = Firebase.firestore

    Button(
                    onClick = {
                        val batch = db.batch()
                        db.collection("posts")
                            .whereEqualTo("uid", "$uid")
                            .get().result.forEach {
                                batch.delete(it.reference)
                            }
                        batch.commit()
                            .addOnSuccessListener {
                                navController.navigate("Login")
                            }
                    }
```

And this is the error message.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is not yet complete
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkState(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw.zzf(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:1)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw.getResult(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:1)
    at com.example.**app.DeleteAccountsViewKt$DeleteAccounts$1$5$1$1.invoke(DeleteAccountsView.kt:124)
    at com.example.**app.DeleteAccountsViewKt$DeleteAccounts$1$5$1$1.invoke(DeleteAccountsView.kt:117)
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

I tried another code and this works. But I don't know if this is correct.

```
val batch = db.batch()
                        db.collection("posts")
                            .whereEqualTo("uid", uid)
                            .get()
                            .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                                for (document in result) {
                                    batch.delete(document.reference)
                                }
                  
              batch.commit()
```

Comment: Have you tried Micro's recommendation?

Comment: I considered to use Cloud Function, but for now, I'd like to go forward without it. I saw many articles to delete multiple documents from Firestore but I only can understand Kotlin and I'm still struggling with it.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible there are too many documents to delete in your Android client. If you read the documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#collections It says that batch deleting documents in a client is not recommended.

You could try writing a [Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions) to batch delete a lot of documents instead.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Yes, the document says " Deleting collections from an Android client is not recommended." but what I want to do is to delete chosen documents in a collection. For my case, isn't batch deleting recommended, either?

Comment: @Yuki If you have maybe a dozen or so documents to delete at once, you could do a loop and delete them one by one using https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#delete_documents. But if you are deleting a lot of documents, you would be wise to follow what the documentation says and do that in a Cloud Function or some other backend service.

Comment: I see. My case applies to the former one, I suppose. Not hundreds but a dozen/dozens. Still I don't know what's wrong with the code above. Actually, I tried another code(also above) and it works, but I'm not sure if it is correct.

Comment: @Yuki Your second code looks correct. And if it works, then that is even better.