# How to create a new Firestore document without data?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a new document without any data (any fields) in it. But I can't find a way.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Is there a use case where saving non-existant data would apply?

Answer (score 5):

> I am trying to create a new document without any data (any fields) in it. But I can't find a way.

There is no way you can create a document without any data. You can use the following lines of code:

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
let docRef = db.collection("yourCollection").document("yourDocument")
let documentID = docRef.documentID
```

But this should give you **only** the id of the document. Please note that it doesn't mean that it will create a document for you. With other words, it merely "reserves" an id for a document in a particular collection. So for a document to actualy exist, you should add at least a property of any type. It can even hold a `null` value. In fact, why to have a document if it doesn't hold anything?

However, if you want to create a subcollection within a document, you can use a document that actually does not exist. It will be displayed in *italic*, as explained in my answer from the following post:

- [Firestore document/subcollection is not existing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53208658/firestore-document-subcollection-is-not-existing)

Answer (score 3):

You can use set() and provide an empty object.

```
firebase.firestore().collection('myCollection').doc('docId').set({})
```

Comment: Thanks ! Worked with dart as well. I think this should be the accepted answer :)