# How to create a collection inside a document?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing a Flutter application with Firebase. When creating a user I am doing:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(user.uid).setData({
        'name': name + ' ' + surname,
        'email': user.email,
        'registerDate' : DateTime.now(),
        'isEmailVerified': user.isEmailVerified,
        'location': location,
        'photoUrl': user.photoUrl,
        'votes' : {},

      });
```

I want the "votes" to be a collection and contain documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to create a collection inside a document?

If you need a subcollection under your `uid` document that should contain votes, then use the following lines of code:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(user.uid)
    .collection('votes').document(vote)
    .setData({/* ... */});
```

In which `vote` is an object that is added under `votes` subcollection.

If you want to add the collection right after you added the user to the `users` collection, then check when the `setData()` operation completes and right after that write the `vote` object to the above reference.

One more thing to remember is that in Cloud Firestore documents and subcollections don't work like filesystem files and directories. Please also see my answer from the following post:

> [Firestore document/subcollection is not existing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53208658/firestore-document-subcollection-is-not-existing/53208768)

Comment: Could you provide a little more guidance as to the details of this implementation?

Comment: As in how to.. "check when the setData() operation completes and right after that write the vote object to the above reference."

Comment: @metamonkey OP's question is "How to create a collection inside a document?". Regarding the check on how to see when the operation completes, sounds as another question.

Comment: You got me there.