# Unable to fetch data from Firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently creating an entry in the Firestore as following:

```swift
db.collection(userId).document(title).collection(subTitle).addDocument(data: [
   "key": "value"
])
```

I'm fetching the data as following. I understand that Firebase only allows shallow queries and I'm only looking to get the list of immediate documents (and not the sub collections):

```swift
self?.db.collection(user!.uid)
    .addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, error in
        guard let document = documentSnapshot else {
            print("Error fetching document: \(error!)")
            return
        }
        
        print("document", document)
        document.documents.forEach { (snapshot) in
            print("snapshot", snapshot)
            let data = snapshot.data()
            print("data", data)
        }

    }
```

But, I'm only getting `<FIRQuerySnapshot: 0x7fba4cd2baa0>` from `document` and there's nothing to be parsed.

I've also tried:

```swift
self?.db.collection(user!.uid).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
    } else {
        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
            print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
            
        }
    }
}
```

I get the same result as above.

However, when I create an entry as following (without the sub collection), I can retrieve the data perfectly fine:

```swift
self.db.collection(userId).document(title).setData([
    "key": "value"
])
```

[image]

The hierarchy

```
- First collection
   - First document
      - Second collection
         - Second document (with randomly generated ID from "addDocument")
            - Fields
```

What's frustrating is that even if I reference a specific document by its name, the query returns empty:

```swift
let docRef = self?.db.collection(user!.uid).document("0x6cac0720c8537467d7d2dccd9b88b8c757e10dfd3dcb8991ff71a4f8dfe1dd")

docRef!.getDocument { (document, error) in
    if let document = document, document.exists {
        let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
        print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")
    } else {
        print("Document does not exist")
    }
}
```

Comment: `userId` is an odd name for a collection.  Ordinarily that would be a doc name on a "users" collection. It would be worthwhile to share a screen image or two of the hierarchy as it appears in the console.

Comment: @danh Most of the names of the collections and documents are dynamically generated, but when I fetch the data from Firestore, only the hard coded document ("result.hash" in the picture) is fetched, which is also the one without the sub collection. Also, I chose `userId` as the name for a collection because each user will have a collection to themselves.

Comment: Your document doesn't exist which is why you can't read anything. See in the screenshot where there's Start Collection and Add Field below that? If you scroll down ( in the Firebase console ) you'll see this message *This document does not exist, it will not appear in queries or snapshots*. You know the doc doesn't exist when it's italic - that is just a placeholder that contains no data. So the *result.hash* document does exist because it's not italic. See [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53208658/firestore-document-subcollection-is-not-existing)

Comment: I am marking this as a duplicate because the issue/problem is exactly the same as the linked Question/Answer. If it's not a dup, please provide more details and we'll unmark it.

Comment: @Jay why was the document (result.hash) created when there was no sub collection, but didn't get created when I tried to create a sub collection at the same time?

Comment: result.hash has a value (try clicking on it) so therefore it exists and is not just a placeholder. Check the link as it's a pretty good explanation; subcollections can exist within a placeholder (the placeholder will be italic) but if there are fields or documents, THEN the placeholder document will exist (not italic, like result.hash). If it's just a placeholder, then it will not be returned in queries or getDocuments.

Comment: But when I create an entry using the first command in my question, fields and documents do get created. I am specifying `collection(userId)`, `document(title)`, `collection(subTitle)` as well as the fields.  When I click on the last collection, I can see the `key` and `value` listed in the console. I'm not sure why it's regarding the collection I specified as a placeholder.

Comment: A document MUST contain data to exist. A collection within a document is NOT that documents data, it's a separate entity. What you're describing is a collection within a document `collection/document/collection` so the document there in the middle only has a collection, therefore it's a placeholder and doesn't exist. I think there's an overall design issue here as that trailing collection (subtitle) should actually be the documents data. Do this, you say `document(title)` but that's not a title, its a documentID, so add a field in that document called `title` and a value of some string

Answer (score 0):

You say you create a **document** at the **subcollection** `{userId}/{title}/{subTitle}`.  But you haven't stated whether the **document** `{userId}/{title}` has been created yet.

Your query is fetching all documents in the **collection** `{userId}`.  If you haven't created the **document** `{userId}/{title}` then you will not get back any documents.

Firestore paths (collections / documents / subcollections / documents / ...) is not a directory structure.  Creating `a/b/c/d` does not mean that `a/b` will be created as well (though once you create `a/b`, if you had already created `a/b/c/d` then they will be associated).

Comment: I can see in the console that they are getting created. I also updated the question. Not sure if it has to do with the fetching of the subcollection being asynchronous, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Are you using [FlutterFire](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview) ?

Comment: No. Does it work with Swift? I'm just baffled that i'm having difficulty with such  rudimentary querying from Firestore. All I literally want to do is get all the documents within a collection. I shouldn't have to use another library on top of Firebase.

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  Did a search and came across some Flutter threads...and forgot that you are on Swift.

Comment: Based on the screenshot above of the Firebase Console, it seems that the datatype of the document ID is different than a string?  If manually create a new docs with an ID of "foobar", does it "look different" in the list (compare the look of the `0x6cac0720c85374` with the `result.hash`).  Could it be that you've created docs w/ IDs that are hex values, not strings (as your query is trying to fetch)?  What happens if you change your above query code by removing the double-quotes?  `self?.db.collection(user!.uid).document(0x6cac0720c8537467d7d2dccd9b88b8c757e10dfd3dcb8991ff71a4f8dfe1dd)`