# Firebase: Delete documents without a subcollection inside them

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection named "departments" with a subcollection inside named "users". I want to delete all the documents in "departments" without documents in the users sub-collection or without the sub-collection users.

Any ideas of how to find the documents to delete?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a structure that looks like this:

```
Firestore-root
  |
  --- departments (collection)
        |
        --- $departmentId (document)
               |
               --- users (collection)
                    |
                    --- $uid (document)
                         |
                         --- //user data
```

To be able to achieve this:

> I want to delete all the documents in "departments" without documents in the `users` sub-collection.

You have to get all documents in the `users` sub-collection and delete them. But remember, such an operation [is not really recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49125183/how-to-model-this-structure-to-handle-delete/49125226) by the Firebase team to be done on the client, if you have a large number of documents inside your collection. However, for a small number of documents, it will work.

The most important thing in this operation is that if you delete those documents, the sub-collections will continue to exist, and [deleted documents will be displayed in *italic*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53208658/firestore-document-subcollection-is-not-existing/53208768).

Only in the Realtime Database, if you delete a node, you delete it with all the data that exists beneath it. But here is not the case, so no worries.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to delete documents that don't have subcollection, you must query the `departments` collection and iterate the documents to check whether they have the subcollection `users` on it. See sample code below:

```
const db = getFirestore();

// `departments` reference.
const departmentsRef = query(collection(db, "departments"));
// Gets all documents from the department's reference.
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(departmentsRef);

// Iterate the documents.
querySnapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {

  // `users` reference.
  const usersRef = query(collection(db, "departments", doc.id, "users"));
  
  // Check if the document has the `users` collection
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(usersRef)
  .then((usersDoc) => {
    
    // Check if the `users` subcollection exists
    // Also counts the documents of the subcollection. 
    if (!usersDoc.size) {
      // Deletes the document from the document reference.
      deleteDoc(doc.ref);
    }
  });
});
```