# Flutter Firebase get document count

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get a count of documents from Firebase. However, I realized that if a document has an no fields, it is not counted.

```
Stream<int> sumOfDoc() async* {
  var snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("GHANA SUPPORT CENTER")
      .get();
  yield snapshot.docs.length;
}
```

I get the count to be zero even though there are docs.

I want the total number of docs in the `"GHANA SUPPORT CENTER"` collection. But these docs have no field. However, each doc has a sub-collection with fields in them. I'm not interested in the sub-collection. I'm interested in the sum of docs in the main collection (which have no fields). How do I do it?

[image: support center collection]

[image: chat sub-collection]

Answer (score 0):

> I realized that if a document has an empty field, it is considered as zero.

No, if a document doesn't exist it is not taken into consideration when you want to count them. The documents that exist inside the `GHANA SUPPORT CENTER` collection don't exist. Why do I say that, it's because those document IDs are [written in italics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53208768/5246885).

If you want to count such documents, you have to add at least a field of any type inside those documents. The field can even hold a `null` value.

One very important thing is that when you call `get()`, you'll have to pay a number of read operations that is equal to the number of documents that exist in that collection. Which may be expensive if you have a lot of documents. The best solution in this case is to use aggregation queries like [COUNT()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries), where you'll have to pay one document read for each up to 1,000 matches. So counts resulting in 0–1000 are charged as 1 document read, 1001–2000 as 2 document reads, and so on.

Comment: Hey there. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?