# Android Firebase document id fetch

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to fetch multiple document IDs from my collection so I can further access the collection within those documents, but when I try to check the documents.size it says that the size is 0 even though I have data in my Firebase Collection.

```
val allGamesDocumentSnapshot = firestore.collection(DatabaseConstants.ALL_GAMES)
            .get()
            .await()

Log.v(TAG, allGamesDocumentSnapshot.documents.size.toString())
```

[image: log response]

[image: the database]

[image: values from DatabaseConstants class]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting zero because there are no documents inside the `All_Games` collection. Why do I say that? It's because the `ac53...c880` document [doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53208658/firestore-document-subcollection-is-not-existing/53208768). That's the reason why it is displayed in *italics*.

If you want to calculate the number of documents inside the collection, you have to add at least a field inside the document. I see that inside the document there is a sub-collection. If want to the documents that exist inside the `Game_Data` sub-collection, then you have to create a reference that points to that sub-collection. This is because the queries in Firestore are shallow, they only get items from the collection that the query is run against. There is no way to get documents from a top-level collection and sub-collections in one go.

**Edit:**

To create a reference that points to `Game_Data` sub-collection, please use the following `CollectionReference` object:

```
val allGamesDocumentSnapshot = firestore
             .collection(DatabaseConstants.ALL_GAMES)
             .document("ac53...c880")
             .collection(DatabaseConstants.Game_Data)
             .get()
             .await()
```

Comment: could you give me a code snippet for that, please ?

Comment: A code snippet for what exactly?

Comment: getting a reference in order to retrieve the data from the sub-collection

Comment: Sure, I'll update my question right away.

Comment: Please check my updated answer and tell me if it works for you.

Comment: This works, but I was also wondering if there is a way to retrieve the id of the document in another way, using firebase querries for when the "All_Games" collection will have more* than just 1 document, so I don't have to hardcode the path.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using a [Firestore collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries).

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the below documents to get an idea

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#initialize