# How to delete nested collections from an empty document in Firestore?

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore, document-database

I have the following structure for one of my collections on Firestore:

```
main_database/root/comments/{commentId}/message: str
main_database/root/comments/{commentId}/replies/{replyId}/message: str
```

I tried to remove all documents from the root by deleting the root document:

```
alerts_database.delete_document(document_path=["main_database", "root"])

...

def delete_document(self, document_path: List[str]) -> None:
    document_reference = self.get_document_reference_from_path(path=document_path)
    collection_list = self.get_document_collection_list(document_reference=document_reference)
    for collection in collection_list:
        self.delete_collection(collection_reference=collection)
    logger.warning(f"Deleting document: {document_path}.")
    document_reference.delete()
```

However, this only deleted all the documents but not the replies. As such I am stuck with replies in an empty document.

How can I flush the database at the main_database/root level?

[image]

Comment: So you want to delete the entire `root` collection with all documents within it?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: You have to delete all documents within the collection, and in the end, the collection will disappear automatically. Give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: Yes I got that, but how do you do that recursively. What if you have 10k documents.

Comment: I think that this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49125183/how-to-model-this-structure-to-handle-delete/49125226) might help. It's written in Java but I'm sure you can find something similar in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging, I found that you can use the firebase-cli with the `--recursive` tag to recursively delete the entire collection and subcollections as follows:

```
firebase firestore:delete "foo/bar" --recursive --project=PROJECT_ID
```